# Attempting to limit memory to an application

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, java-server

I have searched and read many posts on limiting memories on java apps on this site. I know that it is not recommended, but if I really need to limit the maximum RAM used on my application. How do I do so?

My current application is taken from `Oracle tutorial` site. [Knock Knock Server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) I kept the server running, kept sending message from client to server and monitored the memory usage using the `Task Manager`. I noticed the memory kept increasing every time I sends a message. 
I learnt about the `System.gc();` and `Runtime.gc();` as well and I was hoping it might reduce the memory consumption, unfortunately it didn't. As expected.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWriter out =
new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Can any of those commands use the `gc()` command? I also tried the **-Xmx** and **-Xms** hoping it would work as well.

Lastly, if creating a simple java server isn't a good idea. What should I do?

**EDIT:** I am using `-Xms9m` and `-Xmx10m`. And I wish to keep the app running at 10MB, but when it first launched. It can go from 14MB - 17MB, from there it can continue increasing beyond 20MB.

Comment: You should be much more precise with your question. How much memory the program eats, how much will you give it, why can't you give spend more, and what happens when you specify this amount via `-Xmx`. And don't forget to close your streams.

Comment: Have a read at the last link I posted in my original answer. It explains answers to your questions in deep detail.

Comment: @maaartinus I have edited my question to be more precised. I did close my streams if I end the server. But I want to keep the server on all the time.

Comment: Java has some nontrivial overhead and I've never heard about using so little memory, I guess even my washing machine wouldn't mind a few megs more. ;)

Comment: Yea, I know. But that was a requirement given to me to achieve. But there are other reason for this as well. This simple server app will be running on an actual server 24/7. I do not want this simple app to be consuming unnecessary memory. Hence, I want to limit it's maximum memory usage. Of course this server will be changed after I can confirm **control** the memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit memory for jvm (not the heap size ) ulimit -v

To get an idea of the difference between jvm and heap memory, take a look at this excellent article [Taking a Closer Look at Sizing the Java Process](http://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2011/06/taking-a-closer-look-at-sizing-the-java-process.html)

The NativeHeap can be increased or decreased by -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256M (default is 128)

Another interesting read:
[Java Performance Tuning](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-performance-tuning?page=0,1)

Comment: I have came across this during my research on JVM and heap size. That post is confusing as hell to me. :( So I am looking for commands or ways to reduce memory consumption. Or to limit the maximum memory the application can consume. That's why I posted here for solutions. I have considered doing it in PHP if needed, but I have no clue about PHP at all.

Comment: It can be, but to be honest, reducing memory usage and performance tuning generally is confusing and I'm afraid there's no simple/easy way around it.

Comment: Your 2nd link I have not seen before, will read it up though. And I am not asking for an easy way either. I am looking for a way ^^. 
Where do I use `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256M`? Is it in the cmd?

Comment: @Melvin Lai: You start your process with `java -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256M your_main_class`. But this means 256MB, and you'd like something like 1M, I guess.

Comment: Darn it, it's not working. Memory started at 17MB, I set it to 10MB. Is there a minimum MB I need to set for that command?

Answer (score 0):

@Melvin Lai: make sure you do M not MB. This answered my question and work well.

Comment: You must be new to stackoverflow, the `highlighted` "-Xmx10m" is what I entered. I didn't use MB, I said MB in my sentence because I want to. Please read carefully before giving your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not referring to -Xmx10m. I'm referring to -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256M. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, **do not monitor VM mem usage by Task Manager**. Use GC logging to get exact memory usage of the VM. 
If you see any increase of memory consumption in the GC log, then you have a problem.

Second, Make sure you are properly reusing the Socket/Connection. Not closing the connections could be the cause of that memory increase - if there is any.

Comment: Ok, noted. But if I need the socket to be left open until my server (the whole unit) crashes/hang, what should I do?

Comment: Just keep as you are, only close the socket and streams once it is safe to do so (ie. not being used any longer). Generally you shouldn't be catering for server hanging/crashes [somewhat ironic, [but]] when this happens there isn't much you can do anyway. What you want to focus on is preventing any hanging or crashing in the first place. I've found that creating your sockets and streams within the method [internally] or thread rather than instantiating it within the class [globally] can significantly reduce memory usage.